# How can I give first time customers a discount on their next order?

Tags: customer, coupon, discount

The conditions would be:

1) customers only

2) One time use only

3) must have previous order

#1 and #2 are straight forward, but what is a good approach to only giving this to customers that have placed an order?

Comment: Which Magento version you are using? In EE you can use the concept of Customer Segmentation + Shopping Cart price rules.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to create a new discount type "cashback". This can be done using this observer "adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform".

Once this option is added then you can apply the discount by overriding process function of Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator

In the process function, you will find switch case as follows

> switch ($rule->getSimpleAction())

where you can easily add your new discount type "cashback", in this case you can find out if the customer has placed order before or not, if yes then apply discount other don't apply discount.

The above will work if you are a developer otherwise search for cash back or next order discount on magento connect, there are modules available.

Like -: for M1 https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-next-order-discount.html

and M2 https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-next-order-discount.html

Hope the above helps!

Cheers
S

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the count of the orders that the customer has made:

```
$customer_id = some id;  
$ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);  
$orderCount = $ordersCollection->count();  
if($orderCount == 1){       
    $order = $ordersCollection->getFirstItem();
    //Check order status (closed, complete etc)  
    if($order->getStatusLabel() == "complete"){   
        // apply discount here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this code?